# How to resolve this error message when using a while loop?

Tags: java

I have an exercise where I have to write a method that calculates the angle between the minute and hour hand on a clock. The minutes parameter being from 0-60 and the hours parameter being from 0-24. I think I have it worked out but I am new to java and I'm having trouble with a syntax error (I think)

```
public class W1_E3 {
    public static int timeToAngle(int hours, int minutes){
       while (hours > 12) {
           hours = hours - 12;
        } else {
           minute_val = hours * 5;
           return minute_val * 6;
       }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(timeToAngle(3, 0));
    }
}
```

When I go to compile I get the following:

`.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
 minute_val cannot be resolved to a variable
 minute_val cannot be resolved to a variable
 at W1_E3.timeToAngle(W1_E3.java:5)
 at W1_E3.main(W1_E3.java:11)`

Comment: Your else needs an if. Just delete the else and corresponding curlys.

Comment: @kpie Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiated `minute_val` - Change `minute_val` to `minutes`.

Also, you're missing an if before the else.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop doesn't have an else statement. Did you mean if instead of while?

Answer (score 0):

A while loop statement in C# repeatedly executes a target statement as long as a given condition is true.

You can't use else on `while`, you need a `if` to use a `else`.

Correct code (missing declarations of variables):

```
public class W1_E3 {
    public static int timeToAngle(int hours, int minutes){
       if (hours > 12) {
           hours = hours - 12;
        } else {
           minute_val = hours * 5;
           return minute_val * 6;
       }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(timeToAngle(3, 0));
    }
}
```

C# Loops: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm

C# if/else: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_decision_making.htm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is to do a repeated math operation in your `while` loop, then do something else after. It is not valid to include `else` in a `while` loop.

This code example below seems to fit with your intended logic – do math on `hours` until `hours > 12` is no longer true, then separately do a few other math things and return a value. Just separate things out so you do the second set of things after the while loop completes.

```
public static int timeToAngle(int hours, int minutes) {
    while (hours > 12) {
        hours = hours - 12;
    }

    int minute_val = hours * 5;
    return minute_val * 6;
}
```